# Different ways of defining the conditions in a while loop. (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I wrote a function which works. There is one part in there and it can be written in an alternative manner, but the alternative way of writing it doesn't work, although it should represent the same thing as the original code I wrote. I'd like to know why the alternative way of writing it does not work. When I ran it with the alternative codes, I think it became an infinite loop because there were no outputs.

This is a snippet of the function (The code in question is commented as "#ALTERNATIVE", there are four lines in total):

```
if idx2 > idx 
  idx3 = idx2 - 1 
  while idx3 >= idx  #ALTERNATIVE 1: idx3 > idx
    if arr[idx3] > arr[idx]  
      return idx3
    elsif idx3 == idx #ALTERNATIVE 1: idx3 == idx + 1 or idx3 - 1 == idx
      return idx2
    end
    idx3 -= 1
  end
elsif idx > idx2 
  idx4 = idx2 + 1 
  while idx4 <= idx #ALTERNATIVE 2: idx4 < idx
    if arr[idx4] > arr[idx] 
      return idx4
    elsif idx4 == idx #ALTERNATIVE 2: idx4 == idx - 1 or idx4 + 1 == idx
      return idx2
    end
    idx4 += 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alternate code doesn't work in the cases where `idx` and `idx2` are within `1` of each other.

Imagine `idx == 1` and `idx2 == 2`.

```
if idx2 > idx 
  idx3 = idx2 - 1 # idx3 is equal to 1 and therefore equal to `idx`
  while idx3 > idx # this is false, the while loop is not run
```

And nothing is returned. The same type of situation would be true for the `elsif` clause if `idx == 2` and `idx2 == 1` where the `while` loop would never run.

Comment: Thank you! That's perfectly why! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the alternative code doesn't work, perhaps you've put in an `idx2` equal to `idx` and it exited.

However, I thought it might be prudent to show you how to write this code more idiomatically:

```
def furthest_number_higher_than_base(arr, base, start)
  range = start < base ? start..base : (base..start).to_a.reverse
  range.each { |i| return i if arr[i] > arr[base] }
  start
end
```